# Chrome resolving hostname to wrong address

Tags: google-chrome, dns, routing

When I use Google Chrome on my local PC to access a site running on another system via a non-FQDN URL, say `http://mytestbox:8123/` then Chrome is routing the request to the IP address of my local PC if there is a site running on the same port (not to `localhost`, e.g. `127.0.0.1`, but to the actual external IP address of my local PC).

I've tried clearing all my browsing data including the DNS caches, etc., without success, although I wouldn't expect the DNS cache to be an issue, as `mytestbox` has only ever been associated with that system; it's **never** been associated with my local PC, so it shouldn't be an "out-of-date" routing data issue.

If I shut down the service running on my local PC at the port in question and try again, then Chrome routes the request to `mytestbox` without any problems; if I re-start the local service the problem comes back.

Why is this happening, and how do I stop it?

Comment: I should add that this is a recent problem that has started to occur in the last week or so.

Comment: Also, if I try to navigate to a non-FQDN which simply doesn't exist but where there is a service running locally on the specified port (e.g. 'http://snurf:8123/'), it fails with an IP address resolution error (as you'd expect).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an entry to your Hosts file mapping the IP address to the hostname. You'll need to have administrator privileges to do this.

- Open a Run prompt (`⊞ Win`+`R`) and type "drivers"
- Click into the etc folder and open the hosts file in an editor
- Look for an existing entry for `mytestbox` that says something like

  `mytestbox    192.168.1.234`

(The IP address here is just an example.)

- If it's there, check (and correct) the IP address.
- If it's not, add a new entry on a line on its own with the correct IP address.
- Save the file (you might need to force the save)

Now re-open Chrome and see if this has fixed the problem.

Comment: Hi there! I know you're trying to help, but you didn't even explain what that actually does (which is - add an overwrite entry to hosts file), and I can't possibly imagine where you got the idea that address of the asker's testbox is 192.168.1.117 or why you chose that number in particular. And you asked him to "please change IP address" which may be impractical but more importantly -- it's completely unnecessary, should he only actually type the right IP address in the hosts file instead of the "192.168.1.117" you created out of nowhere =P

Comment: Adding the explicit mapping in the etc/hosts file does fix the problem (in Chrome) and it stays fixed if I take it away again, until I restart Chrome and then it's broken again. it still doesn't explain why Chrome is choosing to resolve the IP address incorrectly without there being an explicit mapping in etc/hosts. MS Edge and ping (on the command line) manage to resolve the address correctly in all circumstances.

Comment: Hi, Abhay. I've re-written your answer (hopefully it passes peer review) and accepted it, so you should get the credit.